# How to change starting VC, using amslidemenu?

Tags: amslidemenu

When I launch the app, a VC, that associated with 0 number Cell in Table View, appears.
How can I change it to 3rd VC for example?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It is a professional Q & A site. Please visit [ask] a question.

Answer (score 0):

MainVC.m 
override the following in MainVC.m

- (NSIndexPath *)initialIndexPathForLeftMenu;
- (NSIndexPath *)initialIndexPathForRightMenu;

  - (NSIndexPath *)initialIndexPathForRightMenu
    {
    return [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0];
    }

use : ( if using left)

```
- (NSIndexPath *)initialIndexPathForLeftMenu
{
    return [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0];
}
```